# jQuery load() multiple elements from same file

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

Is there an easier way of grabbing elements from the same file without having to load the page a few times?

Currently using this method

```
$('.side-article-title').load(thisURL+' #item-title');
$(".side-article-subtitle").load(thisURL+' #item-subtitle');
$(".side-article-detail").load(thisURL+' #item-detail');
```

Comment: Yes, use `$.get` utility function.

Comment: Could you use $('.side-article-title').load(thisURL+' #item-title, #item-subtitle, #item-detail');

Comment: @AgnosticDev i want the 3 divs to be in different divs not called into the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//Load data
var temp = $('<div/>');
temp.load(thisURL);

//Display data
$('.side-article-title').html($('#item-title',temp));
$(".side-article-subtitle").html($('#item-subtitle',temp));
$(".side-article-detail").html($('#item-detail',temp));
```

Comment: the page being loaded runs jQuery framework and this causes my page to crash as its loading 2 jquery.js files